# Reference request: Derived structure on the moduli stack of Higgs bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, stacks, algebraic-stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry

I am reading **[arXiv:1708.08124](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08124)**. When talking about the moduli stack of Higgs bundles on a projective curve $X$. It is said on page 59, first paragraph that

> It is often better to put
>   derived structures on $X$ and $S$ so that the relative cotangent complex becomes
>   perfect, and then consider the moduli problem on the derived scheme $X$.

I am looking for any explanations/references for that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: See "The equivariant Verlinde formula on the moduli of Higgs bundles" by Halpern-Leistner: https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01754